# Deep linking from another app isn't working for Amazon prime and disney+hotstar

Tags: java, android, deep-linking

It's not possible to send data to amazon prime and disney+hotstar. I was trying to send user to amazon prime when they click a (video) link (e.g. https://www.amazon.com/gp/video/detail/B01MSPI8JN/ref=atv_dp_share_cu_r). I thought it was Amazon prime which doesn't support it. Then I downloaded Amazon shopping and noticed I can successfully send data to Amazon shopping but not Amazon prime neither disney+hotstar app (using a video link of disney+hotstar's). I was reading the [this](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/reports-promo/deeplink-to-the-amazon-client.html) and [this](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/deep-linking-featured-content.html) but, they weren't helpful.

I have made sure that I have downloaded Amazon prime as well as disney application.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(https://www.amazon.com/gp/video/detail/B01MSPI8JN/ref=atv_dp_share_cu_r));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,null));
```

I thought it doesn't work for this link only. But I have tested others also. If you wonder if it works for any other application then I will say that It worked perfectly for netflix, zee5 and many more. If you also wonder why I used Intent.createChooser then I will say that I wanted user to select which app they would like to use to open the link (unfortunately it's useless cause it only opens default web browser).

FYI, I have also tested amzn://video/detail/B01MSPI8JN/ref=atv_dp_share_cu_r instead web URL. But still doesn't work.

If you think it doesn't work cause they didn't implement it , then I will say that I have used reversed engineering to view their manifest and confirmed that they have implemented deep linking (Amazon prime, and Disney even Hotstar). There's another easier way to see, what they actually support if you have Android 11 (I have just figured it out now). Go to app info-> Open by default->Supported links

Comment: [Cross-posted](https://software.codidact.com/posts/287382)

Answer (score 0):

###### There's actually a reason I asked the question. There's some similar (very few) questions available in SO but none was answered ever (there's few answers also but they are completely useless in 2022, perhaps worked perfectly back then)

**Solution** : Choose link correctly. Amazon prime can't access amazon.com/....... but they can access only https://app.primevideo.com/detail?.....
the question is how to find those links? Follow the following steps :

1. Visit Amazon Prime
2. Select a movie/series
3. Click on share button.
4. Click on copy URL (which appears after clicking on the share button).

The URL is available in your clipboard is the correct link. (I can't really test for Disney or hotstar cause they are unavailable in my country also, VPN doesn't help at all, I don't know why. In question, I added cause my client tested it didn't work for him).

---

The short answer : link.

The medium answer : All the problems available are behind the link. Looking at which link send to those apps was useless cause when I looked at those URL, (giving example of Amazon prime) Prime video says supported links are :

1. amazon.de
2. app.primevideo.com
3. watch.amazon.de
4. amazon.co.jp
5. amazon.co.uk
6. watch.amazon.co.jp
7. watch.amazon.co.jp
8. amazon.com
9. watch.amazon.com.

For me, only app.primevideo.com worked. Others were useless. I don't know why (According to code they should work but in reality something else happened).

Comment: Hi @Billy Istiak, the same issue facing with disney+hotstar also can please provide any solution if knew it.